# Combine values from two columns in a data table to a single list

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to build a list of integers from a data table by combining the data in two of the columns in the data table and getting a distinct list of values.

To get the data table.. i am calling a stored procedure (which i don't have the ability to edit)

After I call my method to return the data table that's returned by the stored procedure..
I want to look at two of the columns in the data table and get a list of values that are in these columns.

The data table returned by the stored procedure looks like this:

[image]

I want to get a list of the values in columns MailerKey and BillToKey.
What is the best way to do this? Can I use Linq to do this?

So far I've tried doing:

```
    using(DataTable dt = getCustomers())
    {
        List<int> MailerKeys = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<int>("MailerKey")).Distinct().ToList();
        List<int> BillToKeys = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<int>("BillToKey")).Distinct().ToList();
    }
```

But how can I now combine the values?

By combine I mean, to get a list that contains the distinct values from both columns.. so eg:
I should get back:

```
275
58
250
50
59
99
55
```

Comment: define "combine" ... one list with both values? or one list with instances of class which contains both values as properties/fields

Comment: @Selvin by combine i mean to get a list like this:    275,
    58,
    250,
    50,
    59,
    99,
    55

Comment: after edit: what about `List<T>.AddRange` then `Distinct` ? or `HashSet<T>` iterate and add? or LINQ `Union` ?

Comment: I can do, something like: var result = MailerKeys.AddRange(BillToKeys).Distinct().ToList();

Comment: @Selvin is the way I'm getting the list of MailerKeys and BillToKeys ok to do?  Is there a better way to do it

Comment: seems ok .. as you wana distinct then HashSet is better option ... fx `dt.AsEnumerable().Aggregate(new HashSet<int>(), (hs, x) => {hs.Add(x.Field<int>("MailerKey")); ) hs.Add(x.Field<int>("BillToKey")); return hs;})` also you only iterrate `dt` once with this code or `dt.AsEnumerable().SelectMany(x => new int[] { x.Field<int>("BillToKey"), x.Field<int>("MailerKey") }).Distinct().ToList()`

Answer (score 2):

You could:

- create a `HashSet<int>` and add both lists to it;
- add one list to the other and use `Distinct` from `System.Linq`.

For example:

```
var a = new[] { 1, 2 }; // Could be any IEnumerale<int>
var b = new[] { 2, 3 }; 

var hash = new HashSet<int>(a);
hash.UnionWith(b);

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", hash)); // Prints 1,2,3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linq to achieve the "combine" step.
First concatenate your lists using Concat, then keep only unique values using Distinct.

```
using(DataTable dt = getCustomers())
{
    var mailerKeys = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<int>("MailerKey")).Distinct().ToArray();
    var billToKeys = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<int>("BillToKey")).Distinct().ToArray();

    var combinedDistinctKeys = mailerKeys.Concat(billToKeys).Distinct();
}
```

Notes:

- 'combinedDistinctKeys' is not yet enumerated, this would occur using ToArray or ToList for example;
- I preferred to use ToArray for the source lists, since I know I will not need List<> features.

For more information about the Concat method from Linq, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.concat?view=net-5.0

Comment: Consider removing the first two `.Distinct().ToArray()` calls (if you don't need `mailerKeys` etc for anything else). They aren't necessary (no point distincting three times when you can do it just once). Also, for the last `Distinct` you likely want to materialise it - either use `ToList` or use a hashset rather than `Distinct`.